# What numbers is X in between?

Tags: ruby, arrays, enums

Given  an array such as [10,42,45,45,61,61,75,90,1240], how do I find what numbers X is in between? For example, if X = 59, the answers would be [45,45,61,61].

It seems like the select enumerator would be perfect for this, but I can't figure out how to select all of the elements on either side.

Comment: you're seeking the closest lower and upper number right? Why 45,45 61,61?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to need the repeated values of the boundaries, don't you? here is a functional approach just as an example. It's O(n), so as pointed out by others you better use a O(log(n)) bisection algorithm if you have big input arrays (note: the value to check must be between `xs.min` and `xs.max`):

```
xs = [10,42,45,45,61,61,75,90,1240]
chk_pairs = xs.chunk { |x| x }.each_cons(2)
boundaries = chk_pairs.detect { |_, (y, ys)| y > 59 }.flat_map { |x, xs| xs }
#=> [45, 45, 61, 61]
```

Comment: `xs.chunk { |x| x }.each_cons(2).find{ |_, (x, xs)| x > 59 }.flat_map { |x, xs| xs }` is probably faster

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input array is always sorted (as your sample is), then you can find the next lower and higher (or possibly equal) numbers using a binary search. In your specific case, you'd apparently then look left and right from there to find all the numbers equal to the next lower/higher you initially found.